# What are the white patches on my succulent?

Tags: containers, succulents

I recently bought this plant ( about 3 weeks before ) and replanted it in my container.I used the desert mix, I live in redwood city CA and it is placed outside and gets a lot of sun ( more than 8 hrs). I have been watering it when the soil get very dry. I noticed these white patches and wasn't sure what to do?[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

It's tips are also getting brown, should I be watering more? But I am afraid of overwatering as I have killed succulents before my overwatering them.

[image]

Comment: I bought it from the outdoor section in home depot and never put it inside my house. But now that I think home depots outdoor section is also covered while where I put it in my house - it gets full hot sun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's sunburn.

When going from indoors/partially-shaded to full sun outdoors, plants need some transition to get used to the sun's intensity and the varying heat.

I've had the same thing happen with Jade Plants.

Put it in a part-Sun location, or behind something that will block the midday sun, and it'll get used to its surroundings.

The burnt leaves will likely remain on the plant. You can leave them or pinch and see if you can get a root off of them.

---

My healthiest Hen and chicks are the ones in part-Sun (no midday blaze). Their range is "full sun to part shade", so it makes sense they're happiest right in the middle. The few I had in full sun did fine, they just weren't quite as boisterous or reproductive as their part sun sisters.